# having a problem running a build with jenkins and gatling

Tags: jenkins, gatling

I'm getting the following error

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'gatling' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\w7116744\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you already have the maven gatling plugin included in the POM, make sure that you run the maven gatling:test command in the directory where your POM is in.

The plugin doesn't check if a pom exist or not. If you are NOT running the mvn gatling:test command in the directory where your pom located, you will always get "No plugin found for prefix 'gatling' in the current project ....."

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `gatling-maven-plugin` is not configured in your `pom.xml`.